# How do I respond politely to a salesperson?

Tags: expressions, politeness, speech

When a sales assistant asks "Can I help you?", can I respond with "No, thanks" ?
Or are there more common ways of responding, instead of using "No, thanks" ?

Comment: In, say, an American department store, *no, thanks* or *no, thank you* are fine, as are *that's all right, thanks* or *I'm fine, thanks* or any of hundreds of other phrases. But this question is on the broad side: how to respond and whether or not to respond at all depends on where in the world you are and the the type of establishment you are in. In, say, a Marrakechi souk, the "best" response is to completely ignore the tout, as any kind of response will be taken as engagement and the first step on the long path to a purchase.

Answer (score 4):

You can say: "I'm just looking, thanks."

Answer (score 4):

You can use a positive sentence instead of a negative one. Examples are:

> I'm fine, thank you.

or

> I got it, thanks.

There are also responses that will signal to the salesperson that you will need their assistance soon:

> Not at the moment, thanks.

If you are just browsing and not sure you want to buy anything you can say:

> I'm just looking, thanks.

Those responses are more pleasant in my view, and they leave place to ask for help later.